# Android Studio won't recognize Log.e

Tags: java, android, logcat

I'm a new programmer and I'm learning java for android development. The problem is when I use `Log.e` in Android Studio it says:

> can not resolve symbol e

I wrote `import android.util.Log;` in first line of my program but it still doesn't work. I also tried restarting android studio, restarting LogCat, creating a new project, restarting the system and launching android emulator then code but it still doesn't work.

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try again inside some function. You write it in class, so Android studio thinks that Log.e is type definition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your `Log.e()` in  method. As it stands it is just sitting in the class. You need something like this.

```
public class MyClass {
    public void MyMethod(){
        Log.e(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Log.e("String","String");